# How to remove newline and trailing space from a list

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have a list that looks some like below.I want to remove all \n and trailing space from this list.

```
list= ['Path', 'Metric Group', 'Metric Type', 'Tue\n23rd', 'Wed\n24th', 'Thu\n25th', '','Week\n23']
```

I tried to use map but it return me a map object not a cleaned list as i expected. I want my result to be like below.Any help is appreciated

```
  ['Path', 'Metric Group', 'Metric Type', 'Tue23rd', 'Wed24th', 'Thu25th','Week23']
  
 data= map(lambda s:s.strip(),list)
```

Comment: Is this in a pandas column? Just wondering why this is tagged as pandas.

Comment: Yes it is. This will be my header column for a dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `strip()` and `replace()` in a list comprehension. I've called your list `li` as `list` is a built-in function of python.

```
li = ['Path', 'Metric Group', 'Metric Type', 'Tue\n23rd', 'Wed\n24th', 'Thu\n25th', '','Week\n23']    
print([e.strip().replace('\n', '') for e in li if e != ''])

# prints:
['Path', 'Metric Group', 'Metric Type', 'Tue23rd', 'Wed24th', 'Thu25th', 'Week23']
```

Note: `strip()` will remove all leading and trailing whitespace. If you only want to remove trailing whitespace then use `rstrip()`.

Comment: It throws an error AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'. May be because i have list and strip is a method for strings

Comment: I've added the list definition to my code, you should be able to run the first two lines and get the ouput under it.

Comment: Make sure you attach .strip() to a loop's control variable, not the list itself

Comment: This code removed all \n but this ' ' character is still there.

Comment: Added a condition to the list comprehension to fix that.